# Lumen API locale for each request by db language code user

Tags: php, laravel, internationalization, locale, lumen

I`m building an API that each user has stored language code in users database.

User database:

```
| id | name  | language_code |
| 1  | Jason | 'en'          |
```

I wanna know from the start that this user`s language code is 'en'. Is there an automatically method to declare this from the start so I will not have to check in every function what is his locale? Maybe in Controller.php's **__construct** function. If yes, how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

In my API, every user needs to be logged in with JWT, so I used this in Controller.php's __construct function

```
public function __construct()
{
    if(!Auth::check()) abort(403, 'Unauthorized');

    $this->user = Auth::user();
    app('translator')->setLocale($this->user->language_code); // 'en', 'ro', etc
}
```